# Maximum value of $(ab+1)(bc+1)(cd+1)(da+1)$: mistake in solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Find maximum value of $(ab+1)(bc+1)(cd+1)(da+1)$ if $abcd=1$ and $\frac{1}{2}≤a,b,c,d≤2$

$$ab+cd≥2(abcd)^{1/2}=2$$
$$da+bc≥2(abcd)^{1/2}=2$$
$$(ab+1)(bc+1)(cd+1)(da+1)≤(\frac{ab+1+bc+1+cd+1+da+1}{4})^4$$
$$\implies ≤(\frac{2+2+4}{4})^4=16$$

However, $(2,2,1/2,1/2)$ gives us $25$, which is clearly greater than $16$. Where is the mistake in my solution? (I already have a different solution that gives the right answer of 25 but if someone has a method similar to my approach which does produce the correct answer, then please share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of your second inequlity sign in the followilng  should be reversed

$$(ab+1)(bc+1)(cd+1)(da+1)≤(\frac{ab+1+bc+1+cd+1+da+1}{4})^4$$
$$\implies ≤(\frac{2+2+4}{4})^4=16$$

Thus your implication is not valid.

Comment: Why? Left is GM, right is AM, and we know GM≤AM

Comment: The second inequality not the first one.

Comment: Ohh I see now, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: thanks for your attention.

Comment: Why do you repeat the error from the answer, rather than correcting it?

Comment: Why should I alter his work without his permission?